# Why is Express Validator not allowing null values in optional fields?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I am using [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/) to validate a form, but many of the fields are optional. I have configured the validator on my route like such:

```
const ExpValidate = require('express-validator');
router.post('/api/posthandler', 
[ ExpValidate.body("TopicID").optional({nullable: true, checkFalsy: true}).trim().isInt(), ]
async function(req, res) {
    const errors = ExpValidate.validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    else {
    // Handle form here

}
```

When a form is submitted with `TopicID: null`, I am getting an error saying:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "value": "null",
            "msg": "Invalid value",
            "param": "TopicID",
            "location": "body"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the same error even if I remove the options `{nullable: true, checkFalsy: true}` from the `optional()` method.

I do not get any error if I just do `ExpValidate.body("TopicID").optional()` but that defeats the point of the validator which is to check `isInt()` if a value is provided.

If I do not submit `TopicID` at all, then I also get no errors.

Is there something wrong with my configuration?

**UPDATE**: Although this question was a while ago, what was happening is that Form data sends **EVERYTHING** as a string. So `null` cannot be passed as `typeof null`, it will be passed as a string `"null"`. Therefore nullable check does not work with Form data (it will work with JSON data however).

Comment: Documentation or github repo can more resoursable for knowing how isInt and trim works,

Comment: before isInt try santiize the value and then put other checks https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js#validators

Comment: @KunalAwasthi I do not get any error if I just do `ExpValidate.body("TopicID").optional()` but that defeats the point of the validator which is to check `isInt()` if a value is provided. I need to check that it is an integer if a value is provided. I thought thats what optional does?

Answer (score 13):

On a hunch I tried reversing the method calls. This validator worked for me:

```
body("date_field").isDate().optional({ nullable: true }),
```

using this input:

```
{
  "date_field": null
}
```

Looks like the `optional()` call needs to be last!

Comment: Great catch, will give it a try!

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this, validator works for me

```
check
    .body('DCFMethodWeight')
    .isInt()
    .optional({ nullable: true, checkFalsy: true })
```

I think issue has resolved in latest updates, using the 6.3.1 version.

Comment: Although this question was a while ago, what was happening is that Form data sends EVERYTHING as a string. So `null` cannot be passed as type `null`, it will be passed as a string `'null'`. Therefore nullable check does not work on Form data.

Answer (score 1):

After much testing and contrary to the [docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#optionaloptions), it turns out that you cannot pass `TopicID: null` but you can pass `TopicID: ""` and it will be treated as optional.

Might be a bug, don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I tried researching but couldn't find a good, simplistic solution, so I tried the following approach to allow null values in case of optional validation:

```
 body('date_field')
.optional()
.if(value=>value!==null)
.isInt().withMessage('Please enter a valid number!')
```